# How to compare rows of the same table by dates? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Gurus, I'm looking for some help with code to compare rows to one another WITH certain constraints. Below is a small portion of what I'm looking at in my table. What I want to be able to do is return only the rows hat have a Review_Detail_Status of Confirmed WITH a Fax Date that is greater than the Insufficient row's Review_Date. Note: I will be comparing batches that have the same Processing_Instance.

```
Processing_Instance    Review_Id              GMPI                   MemberID               Review_Date             FAX_DATE    REVIEW_DETAIL_STATUS
    ------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------
    23760               11359973               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-30 00:00:00.000 2017-03-27 00:00:00.000 Insufficient
    23760               11237889               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-02-28 00:00:00.000 Insufficient
    23760               11359973               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-30 00:00:00.000 2017-03-27 00:00:00.000 Confirmed
    23760               11359973               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-30 00:00:00.000 2017-03-27 00:00:00.000 Confirmed
    23760               11237889               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-02-28 00:00:00.000 Insufficient
```

Right now, I have this code.

```
SELECT Processing_Instance,
       Review_Id,
       GMPI,
       MemberID,
       Review_Date,
       ATTESTATION_FAX_DATE,
       REVIEW_DETAIL_STATUS
FROM TEST
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TEST AS WT2
    WHERE WT2.Processing_Instance = TEST.Processing_Instance
    and WT2.GMPI=Test.GMPI
    and WT2.FAX_DATE>TEST.REVIEW_DATE
          /*AND WT2.GMPI = 650775278*/
and WT2.Processing_Instance=23760
);
```

But it returns:

```
Processing_Instance Review_Id              GMPI                   MemberID               Review_Date             FAX_DATE    REVIEW_DETAIL_STATUS
------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
23760               11237889               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-02-28 00:00:00.000 Insufficient
23760               11237889               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 2017-02-28 00:00:00.000 Insufficient
```

I should (theoretically) be getting:

```
 Processing_Instance Review_Id              GMPI                   MemberID               Review_Date             FAX_DATE    REVIEW_DETAIL_STATUS
    ------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
       23760               11359973               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-30 00:00:00.000 2017-03-27 00:00:00.000 Confirmed
        23760               11359973               650775278              300601690600           2017-03-30 00:00:00.000 2017-03-27 00:00:00.000 Confirmed
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you would get that second result set when you have this: `WT2.ATTESTATION_FAX_DATE>TEST.REVIEW_DATE` in your `exists()` `where` clause? Those two rows that you are actually getting are the only two that meet this criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flipping your date comparison, and requiring that the prior instance has a status of `'Insufficient'` and the returned rows are `'Confirmed'`.

```
select 
    Processing_Instance
  , Review_Id
  , gmpi
  , Memberid
  , Review_Date
  , attestation_fax_date
  , review_detail_status
from test
where review_detail_status = 'confirmed'
  and exists (
    select 1
    from test as wt2
    where wt2.Processing_Instance = test.Processing_Instance
      and wt2.gmpi=Test.gmpi
      and wt2.review_detail_status = 'Insufficient'
      and wt2.attestation_fax_date<test.review_date
      and wt2.Processing_Instance=23760      
);
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/htysu28824

returns:

```
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Processing_Instance | Review_Id |   gmpi    |   Memberid   |     Review_Date     | attestation_fax_date | review_detail_status |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|               23760 |  11359973 | 650775278 | 300601690600 | 2017-03-30 00:00:00 | 2017-03-27 00:00:00  | Confirmed            |
|               23760 |  11359973 | 650775278 | 300601690600 | 2017-03-30 00:00:00 | 2017-03-27 00:00:00  | Confirmed            |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your return result as a subquery. This way you get what you want and link it back to whatever table/subqueries you want. But remember, you must use one of the unique ID from the subquery so there's a link. IE: Processing_ID, Review ID, or MemberID should work.

Without knowing your other tables, I'll assume you can link the Processing_Instance ID to other tables

```
Select a.column1, a.column2, a.Processing_Instance_ID, b.* 

 --Whatever table you are linking your subquery below to
 from table a

--This join should only return the 2 rows where the Review Date > Fax Date
--This is your subquery
JOIN (Select Processing_Instance,
             Review_Id,
             GMPI,
             MemberID,
             Review_Date,
             ATTESTATION_FAX_DATE,
             REVIEW_DETAIL_STATUS
     From test
     Where Review_Date > Attestation_Fax_Date
      /***Note: You can also do WHERE Review_detail_status = 'Confirmed' 
      rather  than the date comparison. Regardless, you get the same results 
      **/


   ) b on a.Processing_Instance_ID 
      = b.Processing_Instance
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for, though the result is not as yours?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af37d/10

```
SELECT distinct t1.*
FROM TEST t1
JOIN TEST t2
ON 
      t2.Processing_Instance = t1.Processing_Instance /* comparing batches that have the same Processing_Instance. */
WHERE 
      t1.REVIEW_DETAIL_STATUS = 'Confirmed'         /*have a Review_Detail_Status of Confirmed*/
      and t1.ATTESTATION_FAX_DATE > t2.Review_Date  /*WITH a Fax Date that is greater than the Insufficient row's (see the below) Review_Date*/
      and t2.REVIEW_DETAIL_STATUS = 'Insufficient'  /* the Insufficient row */
```